# recursive binary search in c++ using a bool function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I have an school assignement that requires me to create a recursive Binary search function. I'm not allowed to change the function signature. 
My experience with pointer isn't the best and i think my problem lies there. 
I get an Stackoveflow but i dont really understand way

```
bool contains(const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd, int x)
{
    int length = pEnd - pBegin;//gives me the length of the array
    const int* pMid = pBegin + (length / 2);
    if(length == 1)
    {
        if(*pMid != x)
           return false;
        return true;
    }
    else if(x < *pMid)
        return contains(pBegin, pMid-1, x);
    else 
        return contains(pMid, pEnd, x);
}

void main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");
    int arr[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    bool find = contains(&arr[0], &arr[10], 3);//arr[10] points to the index after the array!
    cout <<"found = "<< find << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and how i could do it in a better way?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: *I get an Stackoveflow* -- Due to probably infinite recursion.  You are calling `contains`, which calls `contains`, which calls `contains`, etc. and never getting out of this call chain until the stack overflows.

Comment: If you're using C++ you need to get out of the habit of using `int arr[10]` and instead use `std::vector<int> arr`.

Comment: On my machine, this works fine.

Comment: @tadman Why?  If you know the size at compile time a naked array is okay.  I would prefer `std::array` but it is not a problem.  `std::vector` is going to require dynamic allocation and there is no reason to pay for that if it is not needed.

Comment: The [constructor for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) gives you a number of ways to define the size. If you want to pre-allocate it, you can. In any case, I doubt you'd feel the pain of dynamic allocation here unless you were doing millions of allocations.The cost is almost inconsequential. In a quick benchmark I found allocating a million of these took about 430ms, or about 43 *microseconds* each.

Comment: Works fine using Visual Studio 2010 C++ console application.  Prints out: **found = 1 Press any key to continue...** I changed nothing in your program, but added these two lines: `#include <iostream>` `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack overflow is due to too deep recursion.
Its unlikely your array is large enough to really be a problem, so what you have is unbounded recursion ... contains() keeps calling itself and fails to detect this.

Look at how this is possible, and add assertions.

Your code assumes 
    pEnd > pBegin

Your code doesn't handle this possibility.

```
#include <assert.h>
bool contains( ... )
{
    assert(pBegin > pEnd);
    ...
```

Now, it will abort if this assumption is incorrect.

There are two possibities for (pEnd > pBegin) being false, namely "<" or "==".
What does your code do in these two cases?

Spoiler below..

> Length can be zero and isn't handled.